# mapping entries of columns from different files using bash

Tags: bash

I have file1 that looks like this:

```
x  y
C5  1
N1  2
C3  3
N2  4
C4  5
```

I have file 2 that looks like this:

```
y1  y2
1   2
2   3
4   5
```

I want to print lines of that form:

@x1 @x2 x1-x2_y1-y2.txt

so that for y1, I look in file1 to find the corresponding x1:

```
@C5 @N1 C5-N1_1-2.txt
@N1 @C3 N1-C3_2-3.txt
```

and so on...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[$2]=$1;next}                         # Store value of $1 into array x as element $2 from file1
FNR==1{next}                                          # Ignore first line
{printf("@%s @%s %s-%s_%s-%s.txt\n",x[$1],x[$1+1],x[$1],x[$1+1],$1,$2)} # print desired output
' file1 file2
```